# Rewrite the innermost for loop as a while statement

Tags: python, while-loop

```
boo_list=[True]*N
primes_foundlist=[]
for prime in range (2,N):
    if boo_list[prime]:
        primes_foundlist.append(str(prime))
        for i in range (prime*prime,N,prime):
            boo_list[i]=False
out_str=' '.join(primes_foundlist)
print("Number of prime numbers found are: ",len(primes_foundlist))
print(out_str)
```

Comment: What's wrong with leaving it as a `for` loop? Though, I think the code overall could use some improvement. It seems this would be [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. As this is working code, you should post to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for advice on ways to improve it.

Comment: it works fine, was curious on how we can do it using while. Tried few ways but couldn't figure out

Comment: Show what you tried and we'll help you understand what you did wrong and how to fix it. We won't write it for you.

Comment: Initialize `i` to the start of the range. The `while` condition should check that it's less than the end of the range. At the end of the loop body, increment `i` by `N`.

Comment: if boo_list[prime]:
        primes_foundlist.append(str(prime))
        i=prime
        while i in range(prime*prime,N,prime):
            boo_list[i]=False

Comment: can anyone explain why this code is not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
boo_list=[True]*N
primes_foundlist=[]
for prime in range (2,N):
    if boo_list[prime]:
        primes_foundlist.append(str(prime))
        i=prime*prime
        while i<N:
            boo_list[i]=False
            i+=prime
out_str=' '.join(primes_foundlist)
print("Number of prime numbers found are: ",len(primes_foundlist))
print(out_str)
```